# Yii2 render database content

Tags: yii2, twig, smarty, render

There is a textarea where user can edit some templates and can use variables like:

```
{{model.user.name}}
```

Application need to replace this variables with data and display HTML output.

We can write a small function that will replace variables from template with data but we need to use a template engine like Twig or Smarty.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-smarty

Now we can use ViewRenderer from Smarty or Twig.

```
$render = new ViewRenderer();
$content = $render->render($this->view,'template.twig',[
       'model' => $model,
]);
```

But I see this error:

```
Unable to find template "template.twig" (looked into: .).
```

How can I use Smarty or Twig to render a template with the content from database in Yii2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found Mustache ( https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php ) and I'm using like this:

```
$m = new \Mustache_Engine();
echo $m->render("Hello {{model.client.firma}}",['model' => $model]);
```

Comment: You were on the right track - see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7309 - Mustache is perfect for your use case. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't create a renderer manually, you configure your application components, like this:

```
[
    'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'twig' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                    'cachePath' => '@runtime/Twig/cache',
                    // Array of twig options:
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
                    'globals' => ['html' => '\yii\helpers\Html'],
                    'uses' => ['yii\bootstrap'],
                ],
                // ...
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

You are telling Yii that there is a renderer to handle templates with the .twig extension.

Then, all you need to do is add the `.twig`extension when calling render in your controller actions:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
        return $this->render('index.twig');
```

Then put your twig templates in the view folders where the views normally go.

Read the documentation for the twig extension: [Twig Extension for Yii 2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-twig/blob/master/docs/guide/installation.md#configuring-application)

If you want to only use twig templates, you can avoid specifying the extension (.twig) if you set the default extension:

```
'components' => [
    'view' => [
        'defaultExtension' => 'twig',
```

Comment: At the end I need to render String content from database, not files. I found a solution for my problem, Mustache.

Comment: Fair enough -  you can use Twig or whatever you like - I seem to have misunderstood what you were asking for.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `twig` component which will wrap around `Twig_Environment`. You can add `yii\twig\Extension` extension if you need. Then you should use it like this:

```
$renderedTemplate = Yii::$app->twig->render($template, $context);
```

If you really need to render a template from a string variable you may implement your own `Twig_LoaderInterface`. There is a `Twig_Loader_String`, but it's deprecated and you should not use it.